# Snowflake Migration hangs trying to create a view against column name 'DECLARED_VALUE'

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, flyway

I have a table in Snowflake that has a column called 'DECLARED_VALUE' (decimal field indicating declared monetary value). I am creating a view that references that column (along with others).

When attempting to migrate using Flyway 9.20.0, it validates the migrations, outputs the current version of schema PUBLIC and then just hangs. The JVM behind the scenes is consuming a full core of my CPU, but it never progresses (have left it for 10 minutes).

Cloning the table in Snowflake and changing the column name, the migration works just fine (I tested with 'DV' as the column name).

Lowercasing to 'declared_value' also allows the migration to work.
Adding double quotes "DECLARED_VALUE" also allows the migration to work.

**Is there some hidden Flyway mechanism that gets stuck on a column with the name 'DECLARED_VALUE'?**

Comment: Two things I would look at: first, I would enable logging on [JDBC driver](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-generate-log-file-on-Snowflake-connectors#JDBC) and secondly I would check Snowflake UI Query History to see if a query came in and how it looked like.